# how to unpack a set of tuples passed in a mixins Host class (which ultimately are fowarded to the mixins)

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have the following code which works fine in forwarding various `std::tuples` to the various mixins of my "BaseSensor" host class.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout std::endl
#include <string>   // std::string
#include <map>   // std::map
#include <tuple>   // std::map

using namespace std;

struct BaseSensorData
{
    BaseSensorData(const string & _sensorName)
        : sensorName(_sensorName)
    {}

    const string sensorName;
};

class TrendSensor //mixin for BaseSensor
{
    public:
        TrendSensor( BaseSensorData * bsd , std::tuple<size_t , double > && tp)
        {
            cout << "TrendSensor: " << std::get<0>(tp) << " " << bsd->sensorName << " " << std::get<1>(tp) << endl;
        }
};

typedef struct{ double trough; double peak; } Edges;
class EdgeSensor  //mixin for BaseSensor
{
    public:
        EdgeSensor( BaseSensorData * bsd , std::tuple<size_t , double > && tp)
        {
            cout << "EdgeSensor: " << std::get<0>(tp) << " " << bsd->sensorName << " " << std::get<1>(tp) << endl;
        }
};

class CO2Threshold// : public ThresholdData
{
    std::map<std::string , double>thresholds;

    public:
        CO2Threshold( const double & _toxicThres , const double & _zeroThres , const double & )
        {
            thresholds["toxic"] = _toxicThres;
            thresholds["zero"] = _zeroThres;
            cout << "CO2Threshold: " << _toxicThres << " " << thresholds["zero"] << endl;
        }
};
class O2Threshold// : public ThresholdData
{
    std::map<std::string , double>thresholds;

    public:
        O2Threshold( const double & _toxicThres , const double & _lowThres , const double & _elecChemThres )
        {
            thresholds["toxic"] = _toxicThres;
            thresholds["low"] = _lowThres;
            thresholds["elecchem"] = _elecChemThres;
            cout << "O2Threshold: " << _toxicThres << " " << thresholds["low"] << " " << thresholds["elecchem"] << endl;
        }
};

template<typename ThresholdMixin> //CO2Threshold , O2Threshold , or others ...
class ThresholdSensor : public ThresholdMixin  //mixin for BaseSensor
{
    public:
        ThresholdSensor ( BaseSensorData * bsd
                        , std::tuple<size_t , double , double , double , double> && tp)
            : ThresholdMixin
                ( std::get<2>(tp)
                , std::get<3>(tp)
                , std::get<4>(tp)
                )
        {
            cout << "ThresholdSensor: " << std::get<0>(tp) << " " << bsd->sensorName << " "
                 <<  std::get<1>(tp) << " " << std::get<2>(tp) << " " << std::get<3>(tp) << " " << std::get<4>(tp)
                 << endl;
        }

};

template<typename ... SensorType>
class BaseSensor : public BaseSensorData , public SensorType ... //to my BaseSensor class
{
    size_t windowSize;
    public:
        template<typename ... Args>
        BaseSensor(const string& _sensorName , Args && ... args)
            : BaseSensorData(_sensorName)
            , SensorType( this , std::forward<Args>(args) )...
            , windowSize(0U)
        {
            std::tuple<Args...> arr[sizeof...(SensorType)] = { args ... }; //line A
            /*for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(SensorType); ++i)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Args); ++i)
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }*/
            cout << "BaseSensor: " << /*_windowSize << " " << */sensorName << " " << endl;
        }

};

int main() {
    BaseSensor<ThresholdSensor<O2Threshold> , TrendSensor, EdgeSensor>bs
    {
        string("testSensor")
        , std::make_tuple<size_t , double , double , double , double>( 54U , 2.5f , 10000.3f , 400.5f , 200.3f )
        , std::make_tuple<size_t , double >( 53U , 6.5f )
        , std::make_tuple<size_t , double >( 52U , 3.5f )
    };

    /*BaseSensor<ThresholdSensor<CO2Threshold> , TrendSensor, EdgeSensor>bs5
    {
        string("testSensor")
        , std::make_tuple<size_t , double , double , double , double>( 54U , 2.5f , 10000.3f , 400.5f , 200.3f )
        , std::make_tuple<size_t , double >( 53U , 6.5f )
        , std::make_tuple<size_t , double >( 52U , 3.5f )
    };*/
    //BaseSensor<ThresholdSensor<CO2Threshold> > bs2{string("test"),11U , 12.5f};
    //BaseSensor<TrendSensor> bs3{string("test"), 8U , 10.5f};
    //BaseSensor<EdgeSensor> bs4{string("test"), 6U , 18.5f};

}
```

So in "BaseSensor" the tuples of all mixins (ie the "SensorTypes ...") are forwarded through the "Args ..." parameter pack. This works fine but I need in the `BaseSensor::BaseSensor()` body to get access to those tuples. The syntax for doing that however eludes me.

how can I expand at the same time `SensorType ...` and `Args ...` and categorize the "args" according to tuple? 
With the code above, I get the following in g++ v4.7.1 and c++11 enabled:

```
varcon.cpp:104:64: error: could not convert ‘args#0’ from ‘std::tuple<long unsigned int, double, double, double, double>’ to ‘std::tuple<std::tuple<long unsigned int, double, double, double, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double> >’
varcon.cpp:104:64: error: could not convert ‘args#1’ from ‘std::tuple<long unsigned int, double>’ to ‘std::tuple<std::tuple<long unsigned int, double, double, double, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double> >’
varcon.cpp:104:64: error: could not convert ‘args#2’ from ‘std::tuple<long unsigned int, double>’ to ‘std::tuple<std::tuple<long unsigned int, double, double, double, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double> >’
varcon.cpp:108:59: error: incomplete type ‘std::tuple_size<std::tuple<std::tuple<long unsigned int, double, double, double, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double>, std::tuple<long unsigned int, double> >&>’ used in nested name specifier
```

Comment: Your code compile with my g++ 4.9.2 and my clang++ 3.5; so I suppose you should upgrade the compiler to a more recente version (p.s.: the output of the compiled program is (# rapresent a carriage return) "O2Threshold: 10000.3 400.5 200.3#ThresholdSensor: 54 testSensor 2.5 10000.3 400.5 200.3#TrendSensor: 53 testSensor 6.5#EdgeSensor: 52 testSensor 3.5#BaseSensor: testSensor")

Comment: @max66 hi there. Indeed my code  compiled fine.  I had to uncomment a line in the constructors body.  It is updated now

Comment: I see... but my g++ and my clang++ compile with Line A (`arr` declaration) too; only an obvious warning: "unused variable 'arr'"

Comment: @max66 finally, this is the version that produces this error (I had tried numerous things)

Comment: @W.F. may I draw your attention in this question too?

Comment: @nass You are definitely asking to the community to write your software, a question after the other. Do you know that? This is not the way SO should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want obtain with the following instruction?

```
std::tuple<Args...> arr[sizeof...(SensorType)] = { args ... };
```

The `Args...` pack is a path of differents `std::tuple` types; so your `arr` is an array of tuples of tuples; so you have to feed it with a sequence of tuples of tuples. But the `args...` pack it's only a pack of tuples, not tuples of tuples.

So the error from my clang++

```
tmp_002-11,14,gcc,clang.cpp:93:64: error: no viable conversion from
      'tuple<unsigned long, double, double, double, double>' to
      'tuple<std::tuple<unsigned long, double, double, double, double>,
      std::tuple<unsigned long, double>, std::tuple<unsigned long, double>,
      (no argument), (no argument)>'
```

I suppose you could throw away the array part and define `arr` as

```
std::tuple<Args...> arr { args ... };
```

Next, if you want to access to the single elements, you could write something like

```
std::get<0>(std::get<1>(arr));
```

where the first `std::get` (the internal one) access to a tuple (one of the `args...`) and the second `std::get` (the more external) access to an element of the tuple (`size_t` or `double`).